# Worth investing in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server, mysql

Not trying to start a war here, but I would like some thoughts.

I work for a small nonprofit that is eligible for generous charity licensing from Microsoft. I am the database/web coder and my background is with open source stacks. I am most comfortable using PHP and MySQL.

That said, we are undertaking some large projects and am wondering whether it'd be worth investing in MS Server 2012 as a data staging and reporting system. It would not be used for any production purposes. I am most interested in the server studio management's advanced capabilities for importing and exporting data and for little productivity boosts like Intellisense.

What do you think? Is it worth the 80% discounted costs, or should we remain open source?

Comment: If you're a developer, get MSSQL Server 2012 Developer Edition for under a hundred dollars and see for yourself if it fits your need. Or just install the trial, play with it for a few weeks, and see if you can adjust. While I was working on some MySQL tasks back in the summer I missed the nice tools of MS (Management Studio, Profiler), but maybe I'm not accustomed with something else.

Comment: Agree with some of the points in Ayende's blog (mainly about the buggy UI pre-2012), but some are a bit spurious or overdone. Such as version control; we have our packages in TFS, and .DTSX == XML. That's not to say there isn't a steep learning curve with SSIS.

Comment: If you need more horse power or functionality, check PostgreSQL. It's open source (BSD style license), works great with PHP and comparable with SQL Server functionality. Don't forget to use a connection pool like pgBouncer or pgPool (open source as well)

Comment: I've VTC'd this as any answer given is a matter of opinion, rather than fact. I would however encourage you to visit [the site chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap) where you would undoubtedly trigger a lively debate. Personally I'd suggest that with a reporting focus and 80% discount, SQL Server is worth consideration. [180 day trial download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/get-sql-server/try-it.aspx) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Don't forget 2012 has great integration with PowerPivot/PowerView which allows for millions of rows vs Excel.

Comment: @AliRazeghi I've been doing some work with PP/SSAS Tabular/PowerView lately... I could wax lyrical for hours.

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith I might be pinging you then Mark, I am pushing upgrading our prod enviro to 2012 and setup a reporting enviro with PP/PV for our power users.  Do you have any blogs or writings on the matter before I start?  Your input would be very valuable!

Answer (score 3):

Not worth it for the reasons you gave, especially considering that you're not going to use it for production purposes. Reporting Services is a great platform for reporting, but I'm sure there are Open Source tools and frameworks to help you with that for PHP / MySQL. Ditto Integration Services, especially in 2012 (much better IDE for developing packages) it's a great tool for ETL, data staging and other import / export work, but probably overkill for you.

I'd definitely stick with the open source for now - it's always going to be cheaper for licencing ;-). Especially as the cost model for SQL Server 2012 shifted to a different per core model. We had to disable cores on recent deployments to bring down licencing costs, as we'd bought hardware before-hand (on assumptions of the same cost model as before). Funnily, enough that's how I started out on SQL Server - with a "we must port this to SQL Server, because Oracle licencing just got too expensive" project.

I look after about 16TB of high-transaction throughput SQL Server production databases for international clients. So definitely not anti-SQL Server and make plenty of use of all those tools you mention.